# angularjs: how to change row color based on data array value

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to change the background color of a table row, based on the value of an element in the array.

The element name is: IsValid either false or true.

The Array:

```
var Items = [
    { ID: "50425", Item: "4441",    Agenda: "6", Title: "Comment", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "-2",      Agenda: "694", Title: "Program", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "344",     Agenda: "522", Title: "Action", IsValid: true },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "444",     Agenda: "-1", Title: "Future", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "544",     Agenda: "adfas", Title: "Report", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "6778",    Agenda: "36", Title: "Rights", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "7bbbbb",  Agenda: "327", Title: "Division", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "-1",      Agenda: "4726", Title: "Award", IsValid: false }
];
```

HTML table with ng-repeat and ng-style:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="20%">Item</th>
            <th scope="col" width="20%">Agenda</th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in Items" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getColor(i)}">
            <td scope="row">{{i.AgendaItem}}</td>
            <td>{{i.Item}}</td>
            <td>{{i.Agenda}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Function:

```
$scope.getColor = function (item) {
    var background_color= "";
    if (item.IsValid == false) {
        background_color= '#ac1d2c';
    }

    return background_color;
};
```

When I run the page, the table does not show the background color #ac1d2c (dark red) for the rows that IsValid is false.

Would someone help me figure this out? I am not sure what the error is.

Thank you much,
Erasmo

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple solution that I did, but I hope it works.

Table:

---

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="20%">Item</th>
            <th scope="col" width="20%">Agenda</th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items" style={{setColor(item.IsValid)}}>
            <td>{{item.Item}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Agenda}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Title}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

List and Function:

---

```
$scope.items = [
    { ID: "50425", Item: "4441", Agenda: "6", Title: "Comment", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "-2", Agenda: "694", Title: "Program", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "344", Agenda: "522", Title: "Action", IsValid: true },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "444", Agenda: "-1", Title: "Future", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "544", Agenda: "adfas", Title: "Report", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "6778", Agenda: "36", Title: "Rights", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "7bbbbb", Agenda: "327", Title: "Division", IsValid: false },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "-1", Agenda: "4726", Title: "Award", IsValid: false }
];

$scope.setColor = function(isValid) {
    return "background-color: " + (isValid ? "#51c5e5" : "#f73a18");
}
```

If you want to test it. [plnkr.co](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/15INiw9Dl6Joq6Zz)